# publishing observable to make it *hot*

Tags: node.js, rxjs, rxjs5

I am trying to create a hot observable that does not need to be subscribed too. This is for a library and I would like to give users the ability to call certain methods and avoid the need to call subscribe() to get the observables to fire. Initially I have this:

```
const q = new Queue();

q.add('foo bar baz').subscribe();   // <<< need to call subscribe


Queue.prototype.add = Queue.prototype.enqueue = function (lines) {

    lines = _.flattenDeep([lines]);

    var lockAcquired = false;

    return this.init()
        .flatMap(() => {
            return acquireLock(this)
        })
        .flatMap(() => {
            lockAcquired = true;
            return appendFile(this, lines)
        })
        .flatMap(() => releaseLock(this))
        .catch(err => {
            if (lockAcquired) {
                return releaseLock(this);
            }
            else {
                return makeGenericObservable();
            }
        })


};
```

in order to make the observable hot, I thought I could do something like this:

```
const q = new Queue();

q.add('foo bar baz');  // <<< don't call subscribe

Queue.prototype.add = Queue.prototype.enqueue = function (lines) {

    lines = _.flattenDeep([lines]);

    var lockAcquired = false;

    return this.init()
        .flatMap(() => {
            return acquireLock(this)
        })
        .flatMap(() => {
            lockAcquired = true;
            return appendFile(this, lines)
        })
        .flatMap(() => releaseLock(this))
        .catch(err => {
            if (lockAcquired) {
                return releaseLock(this);
            }
            else {
                return makeGenericObservable();
            }
        })
        .publish()
        .share()  // this too?

};
```

however the problem is when I call `publish()`, nothing happens, and the add method never seems to get fully invoked (I assume the first observable in the sequence never fires at all, because effectively subscribe is not called). But I though `publish()` would automatically invoke the observable chain?

How can I make the observable returned from the add method, *hot*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstood. Hot observable *does* require subscription like a cold one. Difference is that hot uses some external producer (like dome element) and start listen to it on subscription. On the other hand cold observable creates producer internally on subscription.

It results in that you can miss some events with hot observable because external producer knows nothing about subscription and emits independently. And with cold observable you can't miss anything because producer is created on subscription.

Long story short you can build any chain of observable on top of either hot or cold observable but until you subscribe to it nothing will happen.

PS. No need to use `publish` with `share` because latter is [alias](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share) for `.publish().refCount()`.

Comment: "Difference is that hot uses some external producer (like dome element) and start listen to it on subscription. On the other hand cold observable creates producer internally on subscription." - This is incorrect. - The source of an observable is irrelevant for the observable to be hot or cold - the only thing that matters is if the stream is already running before a subscription, which is typically done by a hand full of operators, e.g. `share, publish, publishReplay, ...`, see: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/creating.md#cold-vs-hot-observables

Comment: it's just another word for _being hot_ - but I wanted to point out, that the _hot-/cold-state_ does __not__ depend on the _source/producer_ as you described it in your first paragraph - an observable that uses an external producer can be also cold and an observable that produces the values itself can just as well be hot.

Comment: @olsn, Can you give me an example of cold external producer?

Comment: Also: _"Hot observable does require subscription like a cold one"_ - This is also not 100% accurate - if you use `.publish().connect()` the stream will execute on its own without the need of an additional subscriber - it might be not a very common case, but it definitely possible to have a stream execute without the use of `.subscribe` (maybe worth mentioning, that `connect` practically does an internal `subscribe`)

Comment: @olsn, Documentation link you provided says '_'...This is different from hot observables such as mouse move events or..._". So it treats mouse events observable as hot and in you jsBin you treat mouse events as cold. Why so?

Comment: I don't treat the event itself as cold - the mouse-event itself is _hot_. __But:__ as soon as you extend an existing observable (no matter if hot or cold) -> the newly created observable will be a _cold_ and can on only will turn hot if you use `publish` (or the like). - So in 99% of the cases the source does not matter, because it is never used alone, in 99% of the cases you create new streams by extending some other stream

Comment: @olsn, Ok, I get you. But do not agree with you. For me the difference between cold and hot in: _"Cold observables start running upon subscription... This is different from hot observables.. which are already producing values even before a subscription is active."_ Imagine we have observable how can we know whether it cold or hot? If we get all values from it whenever we subscribe then it is cold.

Comment: @olsn, Consider an example where we retrieve observable that will produce sequential numbers and then subscribe to it after some delay. With `interval` we will get [cold behavior](http://jsbin.com/zasopaquto/1/edit?js,console,output). Both subscribers will get items from the start. With mouse clicks we will get [hot behavior](http://jsbin.com/rehaqahelu/edit?js,console,output). Click on the square before subscription will be lost. [Addition](http://jsbin.com/xurinimuvo/1/edit?js,console,output) of `do` to the observable will not convert it to cold.

Comment: @olsn And indeed we can [convert](http://jsbin.com/toramawijo/1/edit?js,console,output) cold observable to hot so that first events are lost. We even can [convert](http://jsbin.com/yalolirocu/1/edit?js,console,output) it to warm.

Comment: _"Cold observables start running upon subscription... This is different from hot observables.. which are already producing values even before a subscription is active."_ -> This is perfectly __accurate__ and __correct__! - However by extend a hot observable, you get a new observable, and the extended parts will __not__ be hot even if the source is hot. Thus the _hot or cold state_ is __not__ dependant on the source/producer - this is a fact of rxjs and I've even provided an example for this: Your first paragraph is __not__ correct.

Comment: _"Imagine we have observable how can we know whether it cold or hot? If we get all values from it whenever we subscribe then it is cold."_ -> If you just have an observable by its name e.g. `myStream$` there is no way to tell if it is hot or cold - if you get all values upon subscribe it might even be a hot one using `publishReplay()` - but that's also a basic principle of rxjs: The subscribe should not need to worry about if its hot or cold, when subscribing.

Comment: @olsn, https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339

Comment: If you read the article then you should have noticed that it just explains the __internal__ workings of how hot/cold is done __inside__ rxjs - the article even explicitly states in the lower section that this producer-pattern should __not__ be used and instead methods like _share_ or _publish_ ect. Should be used - i think you do mean the correct thing, but don't describe it correctly - if you extend a hot obs(the _source_) it will stay hot, the new obs however will always be cold until you use _share_ e.g. the _producer_ that you mean is a purely internal concept

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `subscribe`, you could manually `.connect()` your stream or `subscribe` it inside your method:

```
const q = new Queue();
q.add('foo bar baz');

Queue.prototype.add = Queue.prototype.enqueue = function (lines) {
    lines = _.flattenDeep([lines]);
    var lockAcquired = false;

    let add$ = this.init()
        .flatMap(() => {
            return acquireLock(this)
        })
        .flatMap(() => {
            lockAcquired = true;
            return appendFile(this, lines)
        })
        .flatMap(() => releaseLock(this))
        .catch(err => {
            if (lockAcquired) {
                return releaseLock(this);
            }
            else {
                return makeGenericObservable();
            }
        })
        .publish();

     add$.connect();
     return add$;  // optional, depends if you even need the stream outside of the add-method
};
```

or as an alternative to use an internal `subscribe`:

```
const q = new Queue();
q.add('foo bar baz');  // <<< don't call subscribe

Queue.prototype.add = Queue.prototype.enqueue = function (lines) {
    lines = _.flattenDeep([lines]);
    var lockAcquired = false;
    let add$ = this.init()
        ...
        .share();

     add$.subscribe();
     return add$;
};
```

Comment: Why does publish go with connect, and share goes with subscribe?

Comment: publish returns  a _ConnectableObservable_, which needs to be _connected_ in order to work, you can still subscribe if you want to but each subscription shares the same stream - _share_ is just an alias for _.publish().refCount()_ - and _refCount_ simply automatically connects  the stream when there is at least 1 subscriber - so the difference is in your specific case just your personal preference if you want to subscribe and have the connection handled automatically or manage the _connect_ yourself.